# Proved or Proven uses

Tags: word-choice

I always thought the verb "to prove" was irregular (prove, proved, proven). Recently, I've heard quite a few times people saying "I was proved wrong" or "It has been proved that he did it" rather than "I was proven wrong".

Are both forms correct?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Hope you don't mind my edit. I recommend sticking to this style so that people will be more inclined to read your question.

Comment: *Prove* has two past participles, *proven* and *proved*.  Here is a previous question on the subject: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/6513/230

Answer (score 2):

Proved is the past form as well as the past participle form of the verb prove, whereas proven is only past participle form of the verb. Proved and proven are interchangeable as long as they are used in the past participle form i.e. used in the passive, the present and the past perfect tenses.  So both of the sentences "I was proved wrong and I was proven wrong are grammatically correct, but the use of proved sounds more natural and common.  In addition, the word "proven"is also used as an adjective such as he is a student of proven ability.