# "proves" vs "is proved" vs "has been proved"

Tags: grammar, difference

The question from the test:

> The atmosphere ___________ to extend several hundred kilometers above the Earth.
>   a. proves
>   b. has been proved
>   c. is proved

Sentences with the blank filled with each option can be found using Google in various materials for learning English, so maybe all of them are possible. However this answer https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/6513/10667 says:

> The perfect version is used when you're talking about something proved in the past.

So I've chosen (b) and it was the wrong answer. What is the correct one?

Comment: You probably don't want *any* of those "proof-based" metaphorical usages. Generally, the construction *X proved to be Y* is only used where *prior to being thoroughly investigated*, X was *not* thought to be Y (i.e. - where the investigation overturned previously-held beliefs). A more common version of OP's example, *without* so much of that potentially unwanted implication, is *"The atmosphere **was found** to extend several hundred kilometers"*. Or ***was shown***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But it's a test question, so (per the test), one answer with prove/proven is ostensibly correct.

Comment: @CarSmack, Lots of test questions are poorly constructed....

Comment: @CarSmack: If it's a "test question" then it's a stupid test, set by a stupid and/or ignorant examiner. All the alternatives (plus **b** and **c** using ***proven***) are perfectly grammatical. Only a more clearly-defined context could allow us to rule *some* versions in or out.

Comment: I specifically did *not* speak to the quality of either the question or to the possible answers. Note the word *ostensibly.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers : The question has no context. Maybe one alternative is more commonly used?

Comment: @Im ieee: Apart from this very "test", Google Books has just two instances of *atmosphere has been proved to extend* (one from 1820, one from 1861). And no instances at all of the other two alternatives here. It's just not a sensible test, so you should consider carefully whether you want to spend (waste?) any more time dealing with whatever source you got it from.

Comment: The complexity is with the word *prove*. I had asked here a question (not getting the link though). *The herb has been proved/proven/is proved for its functionality on the human brain.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any other context, (b) is the best option.  "The atmosphere has been proved to extend several hundred kilometers above the Earth" does the best job of providing the necessary context within the sentence.

"The atmosphere proves to extend several hundred kilometers above the Earth" would sound better if it were preceded by a statement like "When measured using radio-scattering technology".

"The atmosphere is proved to extend several hundred kilometers above the Earth" would sound better if it were preceded by a statement like "In the work of Professor Braun".